# C Array address confusion

Tags: c

Suppose I have the following code:

```
main ()
{
  char string[20];

  printf(" The String is %s \n " , &str);
}
```

What would `printf(" The String is %s \n " ,&str);` give?

Suppose str points to location 200, what would `&str` give??

Comment: I assume you meant &string and not &str.

Comment: if you acutally mean printf( "xxx %s\n", &string); most likely a core dump, sincce string is not assigned and may not contain a 0 to delimit the output.

Comment: and acutally : printf( "xx %s\n", &string) is equivalent to printf("xx %s\n", string )

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you exactly want, but according to the question title, you might want to know a couple of things about array addresses:

```
main ()
{
  char string[20];
  char *str = &string;

  printf("The String addr is %p \n" , &string);
  printf("The String addr is %p \n" , &string[0]);
  printf("The String addr is %p \n" , str);
  printf("The String addr is %p \n" , &str[0]);
}
```

all these are equivalent ways to get the address of the "array". The address of the array is the address of the first element of the array.

Comment: The last 3 are exactly equivalent (type and value) however the first example is of the same value but *different* type - `char(*)[20]` - not `char *`. Nonetheless they'll behave identically.

Comment: It is exactly the same for `struct` (and `union`) types - given `struct { int x; } s;`, `&s` and `&s.x` are the same address, but with different types.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a warning saying that

`%s expects char* but argument 2 has char (*)[20] type.`

The address is not printed, in fact nothing is printed.

Comment: SORRY str is mean to be string

Comment: There is no way that printf can know the type of the variables being passed in...it's a var_args function. It just ASSUMES that it will be `char *` and will treat it as such. It will work fine.

Comment: @banister: Clever compilers are allowed to treat the functions defined by the language, like `printf`, specially - and in fact gcc and glibc together do this, and can present such a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually initialized the array with a string (which you didn't, but let's assume you did) then:

It is of type `char (*)[20]`. It'll give the same output as

```
printf("The String is %s\n", str)
```

`&str` points to the same memory location as `str` but is of different type; namely pointer-to-array. The type of `str` is of type pointer-to-char.